# Absolut value of $z^n$

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z=a+ib$ is a complex number the absolute value of $z$ is: $ \vert  z \vert = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} $. Now I am looking for the the absolut value of $ \vert z^n \vert$, where $n \in \Bbb N$.

Answer (score 3):

**Proposition**

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Then $|z^{n}| = |z|^{n}$.

**Proof**

We shall prove it by induction. For $n = 2$, we shall need the result $|zw| = |z||w|$. Indeed, one has
\begin{align*}
|zw|^{2} = zw\overline{zw} = (z\overline{z})(w\overline{w}) = |z|^{2}|w|^{2} \Longleftrightarrow |zw|^{2} = |z|^{2}|w|^{2} \Longleftrightarrow |zw| = |z||w|.
\end{align*}

If we set $w = z$, we get that $|z^{2}| = |zz| = |z||z| = |z|^{2}$, and we are done.

Let us now assume that $|z^{n}| = |z|^{n}$. Then we have that
\begin{align*}
|z^{n+1}| = |z^{n}z| = |z^{n}||z| = |z|^{n}|z| = |z|^{n+1}
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If
$$z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$$ where $r=\vert  z \vert$,
then using De Moivre's Theorem we have
$$z^n=r^n(\cos n \theta+i\sin n\theta)\implies\vert  z^n \vert=r^n=\vert  z \vert^n$$
Alternatively you can simply prove it using Euler's relation:
$$z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)=re^{i\theta}$$

Answer (score 0):

You just need to calculate power nth of the absolute value of  Z due to a theorem.